# Sorting MYSQL Tag table

Tags: mysql, tags, count

just wondering if it is possible to get the top 10 COUNT results and ordering by COUNT and alphabetically?

I have the following tables,

```
tags
-------
id | title
```

.

```
tagged
------
tag_id | post_id
```

And the following SQL query

```
SELECT tag.*, COUNT(td.tag_ID) AS tagcount
FROM Tagged td
LEFT JOIN Tags tag ON td.tag_ID = tag.tag_ID
GROUP BY td.tag_ID
ORDER BY tagcount DESC, tag.tag_Title ASC
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

---

### **Edit**

Sorry if I didnt explain it properly.

The query works and I didnt add LIMIT 10 due to wanting to see the entire result set first.

The query I have works, however at the following example result

```
tag_ID  tag_Title  tagcount
1          Science  3
3          Chemistry 2
4          Misc      1
5          Maths       1
2          Sport       1
```

I would want Chemistry to come above Science though.

i.e. top ten highest counts.. sorted alphabetically

---

### **Result**

Thanks to you both.. Daniel and Sled.

Here is a working example

```
( 
   SELECT     t.*, COUNT(*) AS tagcount
   FROM       tagged td
   LEFT JOIN  tags t ON (t.id = td.tag_id)
   GROUP BY   td.tag_id
   ORDER BY   tagcount DESC, t.title ASC
   LIMIT      3
) ORDER BY title ASC;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Further to the new comment below:

```
( 
   SELECT     t.*, COUNT(*) AS tagcount
   FROM       tagged td
   LEFT JOIN  tags t ON (t.id = td.tag_id)
   GROUP BY   td.tag_id
   ORDER BY   tagcount DESC, t.title ASC
   LIMIT      3
) ORDER BY title ASC;
```

Result:

```
+------+------------+----------+
| id   | title      | tagcount |
+------+------------+----------+
|    3 | javascript |        2 |
|    1 | mysql      |        2 |
|    2 | php        |        3 |
+------+------------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Simply change the `LIMIT 3` to `LIMIT 10` to get the top 10 instead of the top 3.

---

**Previous Answer:**

Why don't you add a `LIMIT 10` to your query?

```
SELECT     t.*, COUNT(*) AS tagcount
FROM       tagged td
LEFT JOIN  tags t ON (t.id = td.tag_id)
GROUP BY   td.tag_id
ORDER BY   tagcount DESC, t.title ASC
LIMIT      10;
```

Test case:

```
CREATE TABLE tags (id int, title varchar(20));
CREATE TABLE tagged (tag_id int, post_id int);

INSERT INTO tags VALUES (1, 'mysql');
INSERT INTO tags VALUES (2, 'php');
INSERT INTO tags VALUES (3, 'javascript');
INSERT INTO tags VALUES (4, 'c');

INSERT INTO tagged VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO tagged VALUES (2, 1);
INSERT INTO tagged VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT INTO tagged VALUES (2, 2);
INSERT INTO tagged VALUES (3, 3);
INSERT INTO tagged VALUES (2, 4);
INSERT INTO tagged VALUES (3, 4);
INSERT INTO tagged VALUES (4, 5);
```

Result (using `LIMIT 3`):

```
+------+------------+----------+
| id   | title      | tagcount |
+------+------------+----------+
|    2 | php        |        3 |
|    3 | javascript |        2 |
|    1 | mysql      |        2 |
+------+------------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Note how the `[c]` tag fell out of the top 3 results, and rows are ordered alphabetically in case of a tie.

Comment: i would want PHP to come last though because its the alphabetically ASC of the top 3 results. If you know what I mean?

Comment: @Stevanicus: I think I understand now. Updated my answer with a new example. Is this what you intend?

Comment: the only thing if mysql were to be 1, would it still appear in second place? Or would it drop down below PHP... it doesnt on mine.

Answer (score 2):

Does the query work? If yes, you could use `LIMIT 0, 10` to get only the top 10 rows.

```
SELECT tag.*, COUNT(td.tag_ID) AS tagcount
FROM Tagged td
LEFT JOIN gen_Tags tag ON td.tag_ID = tag.tag_ID
GROUP BY td.tag_ID
ORDER BY tagcount DESC, tag.tag_Title ASC LIMIT 0, 10
```

Another thing you might be interested in, is ranking. See here: http://www.fromdual.com/ranking-mysql-results

**Edit**

Maybe a subquery does what you want:

```
SELECT list.* FROM (
  SELECT tag.*, COUNT(td.tag_ID) AS tagcount, 
  FROM Tagged td
  LEFT JOIN gen_Tags tag ON td.tag_ID = tag.tag_ID
  GROUP BY td.tag_ID
  ORDER BY tagcount DESC LIMIT 0, 10
) AS list ORDER BY list.tag_Title ASC, list.tagcount DESC
```

Comment: yea its LIMIT gives me to top 10 rows, but im really looking for the 10 highest numbers, listed alphabetically

Comment: then you have to flip the order:

ORDER BY tag.tag_Title ASC, tagcount DESC LIMIT 0, 10

Comment: yea thats what I thought but then i will get a result 2, 1, 1, 3... the titles may be ASC but I would want a result (count) 2,3,1,1

Comment: if i want the top 2 results. I would get tags with 2 and 1 counts. But really the tag with 3 is higher.

Comment: please check the new query in my answer.